# Numerically solving a 2D oscillating integral

Tags: numerical-integration, optics

I'm having trouble solving this integral numerically:

```
Integrand2 :=  I/λ Holo[ξ, η] E^(I (2 π)/λ r)/r
ResultsTable2 = Table[NIntegrate[Integrand2, {ξ, -20, 20}, {η, -20, 20},
      Method -> "MultidimensionalRule"], {x, -15, 15, 5}, {y, -15, 15, 5}]
```

The function called `Holo` is modelling an aperture that looks like this:

[image]

To put it simply: I'm trying to do *Fresnel* diffraction with this as the aperture.

My goal is to get a 2D inverse *Fourier transform* by summing over the entire `Holo` term (a function of `ξ` and `η`). As you can see from the image, it oscillates rapidly, so unless I integrate over a very small area of `ξ` and `η`, I get the following error:

> NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.

To get a good 2D inverse *Fourier transform*, I need to have a larger area. Ideally, integrating over 100 by 100 would be good. Is there some kind of method or work around that can make this happen?

I can provide more details if needed. I'm new to *Mathematica* and to this site, so any answer is appreciated. I can learn from any comments or suggestions you have :)

EDIT:

I guess to make my question a bit clearer: *how can I numerically integrate a 2D oscillating function?*

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help with this but providing code for `Holo` may help you get answers.

Comment: You can try to increase the `WorkingPrecision` by adding the option `WorkingPrecision->50` (with 50 just as an example). Some general information about numerical integration, their warning messages, and potential solutions can be found [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NumericalIntegration.html). Sufficent code to reproduce your problem seems to be necessary to give a more specific answer.